# Remote Working for a client

Tags: remote, project

After discussion with a client, he offered me remote (work from home) job with him. I am working as a freelancer with him since last few months and now I would like to do remote job for him.

I have two concern about remote work as below:

If I will work with him for a duration, then I can include that duration in my CV and will it include in my experience or not?

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by remote job?  How are the terms different than when freelancing?

Comment: I mean full time work for client from home. As per my discussion with client, he want me employee of his company and I will work from home for him.

Comment: Hi @JayendraKainthola, and welcome to Freelancing.SE! I have put your question on hold, as you are asking about being an employee for a company; this would mean that you are not freelancing, and therefore, is not on topic for us. If you disagree, feel free to meet us in [chat], or make a post on [meta] and let the community decide

Comment: @CanadianLuke, Thanks for your comment. Job will be contract basis not permanent employee of the company. Please let me know if contract job in list of q/a of this site.

Answer (score 3):

In regards to your question about including it in your CV: Absolutely! Your commute (or lack thereof) does not take away from the fact that you performed a service for your client.

When including it though, it should either fill a time gap, or highlight some special skill or knowledge you posses, and not just be there to 'pad' your CV.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can and you should. Even more, once you have finished working with him, ask him for a recommendation letter. You can also ask him if he is willing you enlist him into your reference list.

Your CV represents your experience which can be verified (hopefully). It does not matter if you coded 10 project from company's premises or you coded a rocket for Google from your home. Experience matters only.